# Rails Error "no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot" . How can I set the name of a column with integer in it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, naming-conventions

I am trying to set my column names in a rails model/database in the following migration:

```
 class RenameColsInDemos < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     rename_column(:demos, :ind2Plus ,:Ind.2+)
   end
 end
```

However when I run this migration   get the following error:

```
  rake aborted!

   no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot
       rename_column(:demos, :ind2Plus ,:Ind.2+)
                                              ^
```

How can I set my column names to how I want them to be?

There must be a way. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you can pass a string, i.e. `"Ind.2+"`

Comment: ...or escape it, i.e. `:"Ind.2+"`